# Show result from two unrelated models but have common column and value

Tags: django

Background info: it is for a loan system. Basically, the company gives its clients items that are predefined such as Flour, Raisin etc. Each transaction is documented. Clients pay any time they want without caring for which item they are paying. All it matters to the company is they payback the total amount they awe.

Hence, I came up with these two models:

```
class Give(models.Model):
   client=models.ForeignKey(User)
   quantity=models.DecimalField()
   price=models.DecimalField()
   done_on=models.DateField()
   item=models.ForeignKey(Items)

class PayBacks(models.Model):
   client=models.ForeignKey(User)
   paid_on=models.DateField()
   amount_paid=models.DecimalField()
```

Now, it is the displayed that is mattering to me. I want the output to be something like this (tabular):

```
  Client       Total Borrowed             Total Paid
  Samuel        $100                        $40
  Daniel        $200                        $200
```

So far, I can only do them indepedently (loans and paybacks separately). What is the proper way to get the above result for JSON output:

```
     [{"client":"Samuel","total borrowed":100,"total paid":40}]
```

Comment: You probably want some sort of static sum method for your Gives and PayBacks. The function should take a User as input and filter the gives and takes by that user.

Comment: Can you give me a simple e.g. on how to go about it? I can define the method in both models, right but then how does it go in my views?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate functions to query out sums

```
User.objects.annotate((borrowed=Sum('give__price', distinct=True), paid=Sum('paybacks__amount_paid', distinct=True))
```

Comment: While technically correct, it doesn't go with the current display intention I have in mind.

Comment: What is out of displayed intention, can you elaborate